# Powershell Script Sharepoint Online | how to change a value in a list item (column)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, caml-query, modern-experience

I have a list with a list item/column 'Category'. Let's say Category has values 'A','B', and 'C'.

I want to find all the values which are 'A' and replace it with 'B'.
How should I do it?

I tried the following code but list item is a column. It gives me an error mentioned below code:

```
ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{
    $item["A"] = "B";
    $item.Update();
}
```

The error:

> "Column A does not exist. It may have been deleted..."

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like:

```
$sourceWebURL = "<Site URL>"
$sourceListName = "<List Name>"

$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$spSourceItems = $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Category'] -eq "A"}

$spSourceItems | ForEach-Object {
    $_['Category'] = "B"
    $_.update()
}
```

**Reference**: [How to update list item on conditional basis using PowerShell in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193221/how-to-update-list-item-on-conditional-basis-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/193222)

---

Or based on your code, you can modify it like:

```
ForEach($item in $ListItems)
{
    if($item["Category"] -eq "A") 
    {
         $item["Category"] = "B";
         $item.Update();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!